# Алгоритм использования Escrow для перевода bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin

Пользователь "A" хочет купить *нечто* у пользователя "Б".
Пользователь "Б" имеет *адрес* для получения bitcoin-ов.
Пользователь "А" имеет кнопку подтверждения получения товара.

Куда в этой цепочке вставить *Escrow*?
Что есть *Escrow* в сущности?

Какой должна быть последовательность действий на сервере?

Проясните пожалуйста ситуацию потому что даже вопрос сформулировать трудно.

Answer (score 1):

Ecrow - это гарант, которому доверяют обе стороны

1. Покупатель совершает покупку и перечисляет деньги на escrow счет
2. Продавец, после зачисления денег на этот счет отправляет товар покупателю
3. Покупатель, после получения товара подтверждает получение.
4. После подтверждения получения товара деньги с escrow счета перечисляются на счет продавца
5. Если продавец не отправил товар, то деньги с escrow счета возвращаются на счет покупателя

Comment: То есть Escrow - это еще один адрес, например адрес Администрации площадки где происходит продажа? А ни пользователь "А", ни пользователь "Б" не видят адреса друг друга? Транзакция тоже две? И две комиссии?В сущности программирование сводится к передаче биткоинов на счет администрации, затем дождать подтверждения, и перевести деньги получателю или вернуть обратно?

Comment: @Zergatul не могли бы вы привести упрощенный алгоритм действий в случае использования адреса с мультиподписью? И чей это должен быть адрес?